# iOS: changing a UILabel text of a modal view programmatically

Tags: ios, uilabel, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have an app that has two screens. In the first screen there's a button that opens the second screen as a modal view via a modal segue, and it has a UILabel.

I want this UILabel to have a certain text that varies depending on how many times the user clicks the button (they're hints: the user can only click the button and see the hint three times).
What I'm doing is the following method every time I click the button:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TipModal"]) {
        QuizTipViewController * detailViewController = (QuizTipViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        detailViewController.delegate = self;
        detailViewController.tipText = self.quiz.currentTip;
        [detailViewController.numberTipsText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pistas para la respuesta (usadas %ld de 3)", (long)self.quiz.tipCount]] ;
        NSLog(@"%d", self.quiz.tipCount);
        NSLog(@"%@", detailViewController.numberTipsText.text);
    }
}
```

The last two logs have the following output:

```
2013-05-14 19:10:47.987 QuoteQuiz[1241:c07] 0
2013-05-14 19:10:47.989 QuoteQuiz[1241:c07] Hints (0 out of 3 used)
```

Nevertheless, the text in the UILabel is ALWAYS empty.

In the .h file of the view controller of the modal window, I define the UILabel as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* numberTipsText;
```

and I even created in the implementation file:

```
-(UILabel *)numberTipsText {
    if (!_numberTipsText) {
        _numberTipsText = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    }
    return _numberTipsText;
}
```

Any idea why this could be happening, please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the view controller's view is loaded when you assign the text to the label? If it's not, then you assign your text to the UILabel created in the getter, but when the view is loaded that property is overwritten.

Comment: @MarcinKuptel isn't it supposed to be loaded if `NSLog(@"%@", detailViewController.numberTipsText.text);` is showing output?

Comment: Well, your label is created but the controller's view may not be loaded. Then you have to add your label to the controller's view. If you assign a value to _numberTipsText and then the controller's view is loaded from a nib, your assigned value is destroyed.

Comment: @MarcusAdams it's hooked up.

Comment: @MarcinKuptel how do I do that?

Comment: Just assign your text to an NSString property and then in viewDidLoad set the value of that property as the text of your label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the label has no text is because you assign your text to a label created in your

```
-(UILabel *)numberTipsText
```

getter. Then, when the controller's view is loaded from a nib, the **numberTipsText** property is overwritten with a label loaded from the nib, which does not contain any text. The solution would be to remove the getter that creates a new UILabel and then:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TipModal"]) {
        QuizTipViewController * detailViewController = (QuizTipViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        detailViewController.delegate = self;
        detailViewController.tipText = self.quiz.currentTip;
        //numberOfTipsText is a NSString property
        detailViewController.numberOfTipsText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pistas para la respuesta (usadas %ld de 3)", (long)self.quiz.tipCount];
    }
}
```

In the viewDidLoad method of QuizTipViewController:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.numberOfTipsLabel.text = self.numberOfTipsText;
}
```

Comment: understood, thanks! Is this the standard and normal way to do it? for each label I need to have the label and its IBOutlet AND a NSString property in order to contain the text that its passed?

Comment: If you have a lot of NSString objects you want to pass to another controller then you can put them all in fx a dictionary.